# How to prove the inequality $\det\left(\sum_{i=1}^k{A_i^TA_i}\right) \geq 0$ for matrices $A_1, \dots, A_k\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

I am exploring a mathematical problem involving two natural numbers, $n$ and $k$ ($n, k \geq 1$), and a collection of matrices $A_1, \dots, A_k \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$. The goal is to establish the validity of the following inequality:

$$\det\left(\sum_{i=1}^k{A_i^TA_i}\right) \geq 0.$$

Despite my efforts, I have been unable to devise a proof for this inequality. I have examined properties of matrices in the form $A_i^TA_i$ and attempted to leverage determinant formulas and properties without success. I would greatly appreciate any assistance or hints that could guide me toward a solution for this problem. Your insights are immensely valuable to my understanding of this mathematical challenge.

Comment: What about: $\sum_{i=1}^k{A_i^TA_i}$ is symmetric and positive semidefinite?

Comment: The matrix $C=\sum_{i=1}^{k}A_i^TA_i$ has ab-th element $C_{ab}=\sum_{i=1}^{k} \sum_{j=1}^{n} (A_i)_{ja}(A_i)_{jb}$. Merging the first two sums, you can concatenate all $A_i$ matrices on the row dimension into one big matrix $A$ in $M_{nk,n}$ such that $C=A^TA$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let
$$ B = \sum_{i=1}^k A_i^T A_i. $$

We immediately see that $B$ is symmetric as it is the sum of symmetric matrices.

We also have that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$
$$  x^T B x = x^T \left( \sum_{i=1}^k A_i^T A_i \right) x = \sum_{i=1}^k x^T A_i^T A_i x = \sum_{i=1}^k \|A_ix\|^2 \geq 0, $$
so $B$ is positive semidefinite.

$B$ being symmetric positive semidefinite means all its eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n$ are nonnegative.

We can then conclude that
$$ \det B = \lambda_1 \cdot \lambda_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot \lambda_n \geq 0$$

Comment: Do we need that $B$ is symmetric here? I think being positive semidefinite is enough for saying its eigenvalues are non-negative and complete the proof.

Comment: The symmetry ensures that all the eigenvalues exist, and we need them all to be able to relate them to the determinant of B.